# how to get rows from sqlite db?

Tags: php, sqlite

i am using this PHP code for getting rows but it's getting error

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:db/logs');

$result = $db->exec("SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = $result->fetch(SQLITE_ASSOC))
{

}
```

I am using sqlite3 and php5 and i want to know that

1. am i connecting with right code to the database i've also used `sqlite.open()` but it's also getting error?
2. This `new PDO('sqlite:db/logs')` connect with database but why new is it create new db everytime
3. my main problem is i am getting error where while loop is that

> Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

please help me out this i am newbie in php and sqlite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use `while` using **PDO**, you can use it using **procedural approach**.

Some reference: [REFERENCE LINK](http://blog.digitalneurosurgeon.com/?p=947)

You can use `$db->exec` for `insert` & `update` query. Not when you want to fetch the records.

Try the following changes.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:db/logs');
//connection code here
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users"); //replace exec with query

foreach($result as $row){
    $row['field1'];
    $row['field2'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`PDO::exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) returns the number of rows not an object that you can fetch on.

> PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec() returns 0.

Instead you could use `query()`:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');

foreach($result as $row)
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: can i use while loop instead of foreach?

Comment: @JaiffJJ - No you can not !

Comment: so how can i use while loop?